# Unset Session for Particular Page not in whole Project?

Tags: php

1. Is it Possible to Unset $_SESSION['success'] for only one page?
2. not in whole website

Comment: No this is not possible.

Comment: May i ask why you doing that?

Comment: 1) i have One Condition and one Session inside it in front side, if that condition will true at this time it's Message was display in Admin side.

2)that's why i want to unset this Session in only single page.

Comment: No , not possible

Answer (score 0):

When comes to that page first save the session to cookie, something like this

```
setcookie('cookie_name', $_SESSION['session_value'],  time()+86400, "/",NULL,true);
unset($_SESSION['session_value']);
```

when go to other page set session value using that cookie

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this will help you
For example: "sample.php"  page you unset 
Start of page just assign the session value to one variable and unset that session

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $session_fav = $_SESSION["favanimal"];
 unset($_SESSION['favanimal']);
?>

page contents here

<?php 
 /*At end of the page take that variable which assigned at start of the page*/
 /* again set the session here*/
 $_SESSION["favanimal"] = $session_fav;
?>
```